# Compile errors in string double conversion

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my first time trying to actually do any Java program on my own.

I'm trying to make a program that says whether or not a number is even. For some reason my program doesn't work. It keeps saying that a double is required but that I am supplying an int. I have this parsedouble thing that is supposed to change my string into a double but I guess it is written wrong. Can anyone tell me why?

```
package javaapplication2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class JavaApplication2 {

    public void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        String number;
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your number");
        number = Double.parseDouble(number);
        a = number
        if ( ( number % 2 ) == 0 );
            System.out.println("That is an even number");     

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: no sorry it says i need an int but im supplying a string but the parsedouble is supposed to change the string into a int. but i dont think that it is doing that. am i right?

Comment: first make your main method static. second: remove the line a= number. and change number = Double.parseDouble(number) to  Double d  = Double.parseDouble(number); third: check if d modulo 2

Comment: If i make it static doesnt that mean it does not return a value?

Comment: ok i did what you told me to do and it seems all clear but looks like i have another problem. when i run the program it is giving me the prompt for another program i thought i deleted. the program that i am trying to run i have saved as a java file on my desktop though.

Comment: also does this mean that the parse double cannot be stored in the string variable and i have to create a new variable which is d in this case?

Comment: i dont understand what other program you are linked with.. there are no imports. regarding the parseDouble, it returns a double which you were trying to put into a String. refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Comment: yes, you cant put string in double. you dont actually need to create a double seperately. you can you Double.parseDouble in the if statement itself. and pls remove the semicolon from the if statement

Comment: Check out tbodt's answer below; it fixes all the problems you have with your code.  Also, your question is very basic; you might want to get a little more familiar with Java (and learn how to use the shift key on your keyboard) before asking your next question.

Comment: This question is really just about a series of trivial syntax and semantic errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the  complete code which checks number whether `odd` or `even` and you will find where is mistake in your code.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class JavaApplication2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a;
    String number;
    number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your number");

 //Double d = Double.parseDouble(number);//For Double

 a=Integer.parseInt(number);//Because of you declared a as int

    if ( ( a % 2 ) == 0 )//;
         System.out.println("That is an even number");

    else{
        System.out.println("That is an odd number");
        }
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Following is **output1**:

[image: output1]

**output2**

[image: output2]

**output3**

[image: 3output]

**output4**

[image: 5output]

Answer (score 2):

```
number = Double.parseDouble(number); // error.
```

number is defined as a string, not a double.  You're going to need a `double` variable to hold the parsed value.

```
Double myDouble = Double.parseDouble(number);
```

Comment: Why use the wrapper class instead of the primitive?

Comment: I only addressed the error message that the OP asked about.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with that code:

1. There should be a semicolon after the `a = number` line.
2. The code

   ```
   number = Double.parseDouble(number);
   ```

   doesn't work, because a number isn't a string. What I think you mean is:

   ```
   a = Double.parseDouble(number);
   ```
3. The `parseDouble` function returns a `double`, which is a floating point value. You can't assign that to an `int` which is an integer value. You need to use `Integer.parseInt(number)` instead.
4. The `main` function must be `static`.
5. There shouldn't be a semicolon after the `if` statement.

Because of all these problems, it seems unlikely that this is your real code.

Here's the code incorporating all those corrections:

```
package javaapplication2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        String number;
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your number");
        a = Integer.parseInt(number);
        if ( ( a % 2 ) == 0 )
             System.out.println("That is an even number");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot, "There shouldn't be a semicolon after the `if` statement."

Comment: This code has error: `number` is string and how can you do `( number % 2 ) == 0 `. See my answer